# Cheap AI algorithm for constructing most likely tuples

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis

I am looking for an algorithm to find most likely 2-tuple given the first element of the tuple.

The most likely one is when the two elements have previously been seen together more often in a batch.

Let's say you have an infinite stream of batches:

```
BATCH 1:

border
color
border-radius
dispaly


BATCH 2:

width
height
left
top
color
border


BATCH 3:

border
border-radius
width
height


BATCH 4:

[ and so on ... ]
```

Batches are streaming in continuously and are never ending. The algorithm has to train to be able to know which every two elements in a batch are most likely to appear together.

For example, when a new batch comes in, I ask the algorithm "Please split the batch into a set of 2-tuples by their likelihood of being in one batch."

Lets say the batch number 4 comes in as follows

```
BATCH 4:

border
width
border-radius
height
```

The algorithm would split the batch into two 2-tuples like so:

```
[border, border-radius]
[width, height]
```

Because those elements historically are more likely to be in one batch together.

The algorithm does not have to be exact but rather cheap and operation on probabilities.

Comment: Is this just an example or is this somewhat the size of your real data? Or to be more clear: avg/max batch-size? number of different elements? Are older batches less relevant than newer ones?

Comment: What algorithms have you researched and considered?  What are the trade-offs for your particular application?  There is plenty of literature on N-grams, and N=2 is a (relatively) simple intro example.

Comment: Have a look at frequent itemsets in [association rule mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning). The algorithms described on the wiki page (Apriori, FP growth, ..) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's called frequent 2-itemsets.

But with the tuple restriction, it simply boils down to counting.